# This string cannot be converted to a JSONArray

Tags: android, json

The following string cannot be converted to a JSONArray for some reason. I do not know why:
This is the string:

```
[{"article_number":"2.","article_title":"Supremacy of this Constitution","chapter_id":"1","part_id":"0","article_id":"2"},
{"article_number":"3.","article_title":"Defence of this Constitution","chapter_id":"1","part_id":"0","article_id":"3"}]
```

This is the code:

```
try{
            //Load the sqlite DB here:ARTICLES TABLE
            json_array=new JSONArray(response_articles.trim());
            int len=json_array.length();
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
                JSONObject json_obj=json_array.getJSONObject(i);
                String article_id=json_obj.getString("article_number");
                String part_no=json_obj.getString("article_title");
                System.out.println(article_id+"........................................................................,"+part_no);
                //String chapter_id=json_obj.getString("chapter_number");
                //String chapter=json_obj.getString("constitutionChapters");

            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: The error is: org.json.JSONException: Value ? of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: I am not seeing where the ? is in the string

Comment: `response_articles`  is not equals to json string that you wrote ... end of story

Comment: The response_articles is the variable holding the string above

Comment: Add some code like: `Log.d(APP_NAME, "response_articles = " + response_articles)` before you try to convert it so that you can at least see what the actual text being passed is, because like @Selvin said, that's not it.

Comment: add `Log.d("bla", response_articles);`  before `json_array=new JSONArray(response_articles.trim());` and tell us what you get in LogCat ... and yes, if it has `"` at the start and at the end it does matter ... as `"[]"` is not a valid JSON but `[]` is a valid JSON

Comment: There is a ? at the beginning of the string but it is not visible in the string

Comment: You mean it's not showing in the logcat? Can you post the actual output?

Comment: ?[{"article_number":"2.........

Comment: Yes it is not showing in the logcat

Comment: But when you get a log of the error from the logcat, it shows in the textfile

Comment: What text file is this? Is the JSON being read from a file or fetched from a server?

Comment: The textfile is when you save the logcat log to disk as a txt. Yes the data is coming from a server

Comment: You could do a dirty `json_array = json_array.replaceAll("?", "")` to just get rid of any question marks, but that'll also remove any actual question marks. I'm not sure what else you can do, if it's really not showing in the logcat.

Comment: Tried that already...Its still there. I thing its a serverside problem. Thanx though.